# How to use new keyword dummynet-anchor in pf.conf of Mac OS X

Tags: macos, firewall, pf

Mac OS X introduced a new keyword “dummynet-anchor” in `pf.conf` file, which not used in FreeBSD and OpenBSD. The `ipfw` was removed in Mac OS X 10.10, How to use “dummynet-anchor”?

UPDATE:
 What portion of ruleset will execute by "dummynet-anchor"?

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks, I looked that page nothing about use dummynet with pf in osx 10.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have found out so far about that topic:

You setup your `dummynet` configuration using the command line tool `dnctl` for details. Check out `man dnctl`. This tool allows you to configure pipes and queues. Every pipe/queue has a numeric name, as well as a set of properties (e.g. a bandwidth, a delay, a packet drop rate, etc.)

Example from the man page:

```
dnctl pipe 1 config bw 14Kbit/s queue 10Kbytes
```

This creates a pipe named `1` with a maximum bandwidth of 14 kbps and a backlog buffer of 10 KB (or maybe 10 KiB, the page is not clear about that).

Now you only need a way to tell the system what network packets must go through that pipe and this is done using `pf`:

```
dummynet in all pipe 1
```

This will redirect all incoming traffic to the pipe named `1`.

Even though nowhere documented, the `-s` option of `pfctl` also knows a `dummynet` parameter. E.g. to see the dummynet entries that the *Network Link Conditioner* (ncl) from Apple's Dev Tools is setting, just run:

```
sudo pfctl -a com.apple.nlc/base -s dummynet
```

Here's a sample output:

```
no dummynet quick on lo0 all
dummynet in quick inet all allow-opts pipe 40269
dummynet in quick inet6 all allow-opts pipe 40269
dummynet out quick inet all allow-opts pipe 40270
dummynet out quick inet6 all allow-opts pipe 40270
```

Now let's look up what pipes it has configured:

```
40269:   1.000 Mbit/s  500 ms   50 sl.plr 0.100000 1 queues (1 buckets) droptail
    mask: 0x00 0x00000000/0x0000 -> 0x00000000/0x0000
40270:   1.000 Mbit/s  500 ms   50 sl.plr 0.100000 1 queues (1 buckets) droptail
    mask: 0x00 0x00000000/0x0000 -> 0x00000000/0x0000
```

This matches exactly what I've configured:
[image]
Okay, what is a `dummynet-anchor`? Well, I think it's just an `anchor` but one for `dummynet` rules, similar like there are `nat-anchors` for NAT (Network Address Translation) rules. Running:

```
sudo pfctl -sa
```

I get this output:

```
TRANSLATION RULES:
nat-anchor "com.apple/*" all
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*" all

FILTER RULES:
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble
anchor "com.apple/*" all

DUMMYNET RULES:
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*" all
```

So you see there are different kind of anchors belonging to different rule sections. From where these rules are actually loaded is still a mystery for me. There is a directory `/etc/pf.anchors` on macOS but this one only contains a single file `com.apple` and this file only refers to more anchors:

```
#
# AirDrop anchor point.
#
anchor "200.AirDrop/*"

#
# Application Firewall anchor point.
#
anchor "250.ApplicationFirewall/*"
```

A search for `250.ApplicationFirewall` doesn't find any files or folders with that name on my system.

So I'm sorry, this is not really an answer to your question, I really don't know the answer either. Yet this question is over 3 years old and nobody has answered it at all, so I thought I share my findings here and maybe someone can pick up on it and gain some new insights that way.

Comment: anchor can be added by application, so it may not in any config file.